# Notation about factors

Tags: notation, prime-numbers, terminology

What is the name (if there is one) of the "full factorization representation" of a number, in which also the powers of the factors are (recursively) decomposed until all the numbers used in the representation are primes?

For example: instead of writing: $n = 2^{4} 3 ^{98304}$, write:

$$n = 2^{2^2 } 3 ^{2^{3 \cdot 5} \cdot 3}$$

($4 = 2^2$, $98304 = 2^{15} \cdot 3$, $15 = 3 \cdot 5$)

Comment: Never seen the likes of it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is known as **Prime Power Factor Decomposition**

[Wiki article on Arithmetic Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CE.A9.28n.29.2C_.CF.89.28n.29.2C_.CE.BDp.28n.29_.E2.80.93_prime_power_decomposition)